# Flex Mobile Facebook api: SECURITY WARNING: Please treat

Tags: facebook, api, apache-flex, mobile, air

Trying to login using GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1.swc .

Success 
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

As I see is that received answer from the server
https://m.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
which is not handled by the GraphAPI handleLocationChange

I inserted handler for this case in MobileLoginWindow.as handleLocationChange function, 
but to continue normal execution it's needed
also from some parameters like Token, which not exist in this answer

Some help ?

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem.

Take a look for the Android ANE and iOS ANE here:

Free ANE - 
You can use this: https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook

Paid - You can use "GoViral social networking" - 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

Answer (score 0):

Since October 2 this swc is obsolete. Facebook prohibits the use of stage views on mobile to login the user in the app. You can see it on developer's roadmap http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

The only way to login on mobile now from AS3 is to use an ANE that provides it. Be sure that this ANE use Facebook's official native SDKs or you will get the same error on January 8.